# Load video file from Assets folder to VideoView

Tags: android

I'm using `VideoView` and `MediaController` attached to it
i know how to load a video from the raw folder and how to load a url
but i'm unable to load a local file that sits in the Assets folder

i saw some way to do it with a MediaPlayer and SurfaceView, but i'm seeking a way to do so without changing the all activity and layout

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try using the function `getAssets().open("videofile")`

Comment: and how do i put the openstream into the ViewView ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw....);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```